# Prove that there are no rational solutions

Tags: proof-writing, rational-numbers

Prove that $2r^4 +20r^2 = 15r^3 + 15r - 6$ has no rational solutions without solving for $r$.

My first thought was using remainders upon division, but I'm not sure how to apply this with variables.

Comment: What tools are you allowed to use?  The rational roots theorem?  Modular arithmetic?  There are a number of ways to proceed, so some bounds on the acceptable method are needed.

Comment: The Rational Root Theorem would give you a finite set of possible roots, which you could plug in one by one.

Comment: No rational root theorem. I believe modular arithmetic is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* There are no solutions mod $5$.

Indeed, if $r=x/y$ then $2x^4 \equiv -6 y^4$ or $x^4 \equiv -3 y^4$. Now use Fermat's theorem.

Comment: How do I mod this equation?

Comment: @LetmeKnow : If $5 \mid x$ then $5 \mid y$ and $x/y$ is not in lowest terms.